# NodeJS TCP socket often listen to END event

Tags: node.js, sockets, ubuntu, tcp, keep-alive

We have a Nodejs TCP connection application. What it does is, it accept data from IOT device (data send via SIM). The application resides in Ubuntu 18 machine. The software and IOT device works perfectly when it is in the same region. For example:

The server is in USA, The IOT device is in USA

or

The server is in Australia, The IOT device is in Australia

This scenario works perfectly. However if the server or IOT device is in different region the application often listen to Socket end event. For example:

The server is in USA
The IOT device is in Spain

or

The server is in USA
The IOT device is in Russia

In above instance often times the application listen to socket **END** event due to that, the device reconnect all the time with milliseconds difference.

I then surf around the Google and many recommended to fine tune the Linux default TCP value. https://www.cspsprotocol.com/tcp-keep-alive/ . I then changed the default value and apparently still it's not taking any effect. The current values are

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 10
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 50
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
```

As second step I added the following line in my Nodejs application but still no luck.

```
socket.setKeepAlive(true, 300000);
```

Here's my TCP connection code:

```
const Network = require("net");
const Events = require("events");
const { Signale } = require("signale");


const { PORT = 5252, HOST = "localhost" } = process.env;

const emitter = new Events.EventEmitter();

const logger = new Signale({
    scope: "server"
});

const server = Network.createServer(onClientConnected);

server.on("error", error => {
    if (error.code === "EADDRINUSE") {
        logger.warn(`Port is already in use, retrying ..`);
        setTimeout(() => {
            server.close();
            server.listen(PORT, () => {
                logger.success("Retrying listening to port", PORT, "on host", HOST);
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
});

let deviceConnectTimes = {};

function onClientConnected(socket) {
    const clientName = `${socket.remoteAddress}`;
    const networkLogger = logger.scope(clientName);

    socket.deviceMetadata = null;

    const TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 30;
    socket.setTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS * 1000);

    socket.on("timeout", () => {
        networkLogger.warn(`The socket for ${clientName} has timed out.`);
        socket.end();
    });

    socket.on("error", error => {
        networkLogger.error(error);
    });

    socket.on("end", () => {
        networkLogger.warn(`The socket for ${clientName} has closed or timed out.`);
        console.log("socket end", socket.deviceMetadata);
    });

    socket.on("data", async buffer => {
        networkLogger.debug(buffer.toString("hex"));

        **....More code here**

    });
    socket.setKeepAlive(true, 300000); // New code added to solve the disconnetion issue
}

module.exports.events = emitter;

module.exports.listen = () => {
    server.listen(PORT, () => {
        logger.success("Listening on port", PORT, "on host", HOST);
    });
};
```

Any help would be appreciated, as why it casing the latency if the device or server is in different country.

Answer (score 1):

Trivially, there are two possibilities: 1) It's caused purely by latency or 2) it isn't.

So I'd start with trying to simulate the increase in latency in a test environment (ideally localhost or a simple LAN - I have an ancient 10-base-T hub that works great for this sort of thing). Start with a basic setup, then add latency using something like tc

https://bencane.com/2012/07/16/tc-adding-simulated-network-latency-to-your-linux-server/

If you can repeat the issue locally then you should be able to either see the problem or at least get a PCAP together - then you can post it here and someone should be able to give you a better answer.